# Getting error in , printing pattern in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am try to print a square box using python, but every time i try, it print a straight line.
So i didn't understand what's going on. Code is below.

```
for i in range(6):
  for j in range(6):
    print("*",end="")
    print()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should print a newline in every iteration of the outer for loop.You can try it:

```
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        print("* ",end="")
    print()
```

Output will be:

```
* * * * * * 
* * * * * * 
* * * * * * 
* * * * * * 
* * * * * * 
* * * * * *
```

Answer (score 1):

#### What your code was doing:

After printing a star, the print() function prints a newline.

Try This:

```py
for i in range(6):
  for j in range(6):
    print("*",end="")
  print()
```

May I suggest printing using like a function instead?

```py
def square_stars(n):
        [print("*" * n) for i in range(n)]
```

Test:

```py
square_stars(5)
```

Output:

```
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

Answer (score 1):

Close - rather than printing a new line in the inner loop, you should only print it after every row is printed.

```py
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        print("*", end="")
    print()
```

This will produce a 6 by 6 square of *s:

```
******
******
******
******
******
******
```

Comment: Thanks bro.. issue resolved 

Comment: If your query is done, please mark this as answer

Answer (score 0):

You should print a newline in every iteration of the outer for loop. Currently, your code outputs a newline after every asterisk.
Try changing the scope of the 2nd print statement.